# How to install a curtain rod with a perpendicular wall on one side

Tags: concrete, walls, windows, installation

I have an extremely awkward window configuration that I have no idea how to handle. It seems like most curtain rods want to have a bit of space on both ends of the window to install flat onto the wall but in my case the window is right next to a wall jutting out on the left-hand side so there's no space.

The only thing I can think of is a curtain rod that somehow reaches from that left wall all the way to the right wall (but I can't find any curtain rods that install on the ends?), or install the curtain rod from the ceiling.

However, If I install it onto the ceiling, will that be a problem somehow for the unit above me? Will I run into some kind of weird problem with the ceiling being too difficult to drill into??

I live in an apartment that I'm pretty sure is made out of concrete if that helps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: is the purpose intended for curtain rod purely decorative? Are all the walls in the picture cement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use a standard rod bracket on the right and a cup on the left. If you are mounting to concrete, simple plastic plug anchors should work very well.

[image]

<sub>[source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A41II90)</sub>

[image]

<sub>[source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01A9FBAUY)</sub>

Comment: Could even use the type in the lower pic on both walls, because that wall space to the right would make a nice place for the curtain to be pulled over to (should the OP desire the entire window to be uncovered).

Comment: True, but it's often more decorative to leave the rod knob exposed. A person could do both.

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be a variety of options with various pro/cons

- tension rod, from wall to wall (aren't as strong and curtain would span whole wall)
  [image]
  [source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073Q7Q9B7)
- ceiling mount. Shouldn't be any problems with unit above, slightly harder to drill upside down but doable ([Home Depot video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8kzjZm57NQ) on one way of doing this, [ikea way](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/vidga-single-track-rail-included-ceiling-fittings-white-20492916/))
  [image]
  [source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MRT552R)
  [image]
  [source](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/vidga-single-track-rail-included-ceiling-fittings-white-20492916/)
- [custom pipe curtain rod](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/diy-pipe-curtain-rod/) but only with one bend, making tall L shape-> see @isherwood answer (if walls are cement, this will be the hardest option)

Answer (score 3):

I would use a telescoping (adjustable) rod with the two cups on the opposing walls. That way, you can easily slide the curtains all the way to the right to fully expose the window for maximum sunlight.